# Assume date manually - Updating date with own assumption

Tags: python, date

Basically I have the creation_date for some user in the format as follows:

```
    # Format creation date
    creation_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(creation_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

So it will provide the creation date of user in the year-month-date format.

Then I need to take the date only (IE., `%d`) So I have taken the same as follows:

```
    # Get the day only
    creation_just_day = creation_date.day
    print creation_just_day
```

Now If the the particalar day is in following list I need to assume the day to `'28'`, Which is done as follows:

```
    # Items need to consider for date consideration
    date_assume_list = [29,30,31]

    if creation_just_day in date_assume_list:
            creation_just_day = 28
```

Finally now I need to make the date as follows here using the above assignment.

So it should print the date as follows:

```
2016-01-28
```

Comment: Do you want to modify `creation_date` or do you want to create a new `datetime` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) method. This method returns a new `datetime` object with one or more of the values of the original `datetime` object replaced. Of course, you can overwrite the original `datetime` object if you don't need it anymore.

For example,

```
import datetime

for creation_date in ('2016-02-05', '2016-01-29', '2015-12-31',): 
    creation_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(creation_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    print '\nBefore:', creation_date
    if creation_date.day in (29, 30, 31):
        creation_date = creation_date.replace(day=28)
    print 'After: ', creation_date
```

**output**

```
Before: 2016-02-05 00:00:00
After:  2016-02-05 00:00:00

Before: 2016-01-29 00:00:00
After:  2016-01-28 00:00:00

Before: 2015-12-31 00:00:00
After:  2015-12-28 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This line, where you use the other info from creation_date as well:

```
print('%s-%s-%s' % (creation_date.year, creation_date.month, creation_just_day))
```